# Convert Photoshop Actions into iOS App Image Filters?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

We are working in a iOS camera application and we have a question about Converting photoshop actions filters to iOS image filters .

Example : taking a photoshop action file and turn it into image filters in the iPhone app , is there any way to do it ?

any question or help will be appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: As I told you the last time you asked this, before you deleted the question, Photoshop actions are groupings of filters. You're going to need to examine each one, figure out what filters it uses and write code to run those filters. You'll need to use Core Image, my GPUImage framework, or CPU-bound manipulation of the raw image bytes to do the filtering portion. As it stands, this question is too broad to give a specific answer, so perhaps you could refine it to focus on the portion of this process you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between Photoshop action filters and iOS image filters. The only way you can do it is to implement most of photoshop image processing code by yourself using iOS API.